# Pay As You Earn loan filling jointly

Tags: united-states, taxes, student-loan, germany

My wife(US) has a debt in Germany for a master, she's paying on a pay as you earn, and since now we are married we filed the taxes jointly, and my income made the 1040 be the triple of the 1040 she would have filing separately.
If we have to pay the 10% of the jointly 1040 I need to prepare financially, is someone able to tell me what to expect, or if in the worst case if is possible to be fixed?
We sent both the 1040 and my wife W2 to demonstrate her income.

Comment: You'll need to read the contract. "Pay as you earn" - does "you" refer to her personally, or to her as part of the household? Do you have community income that's split with her? You'll need to dig into details.

Comment: This could be a case where it may be advantageous for you to file a married but separate return.  It is a pain, and a bit more costly, but depending upon the nuisances of the German law in this regard it may help you two out.  While sound advice would be to seek a tax professional's help, I imagine one being well versed in both US tax code and this German law will be very difficult to find.